# Calendar Sync with devices for my website

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I am an asp.net programmer. I'm trying to sync the calendar in my website with other devices, outlook etc. Registered users of my website should be able to sync calendar using my website account itself. I have done lots of googling, but I didn't find a better API that correctly satisfy my requirement. Can anyone help me out of this? I want an immediate help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171349/time-sync-between-two-processes-net OR http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/03/02/synchronization-services-for-ado-net-for-devices-improving-performance-by-skipping-tables-that-don-t-need-synchronization.aspx ? IS this what you are looking for? cheers!

Comment: Thanks for quick response.                                           I had gone through both the links you have given.  [link]"blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/03/02/… "will help me to track changes in database. But, what I wanted is, when a paid user sync their phone or outlook, the changes that have occurred in my website calender should be found in that devices. It can be iphone, ipad, blackbery or anything.                                             Hope you are clear with my requirement. Thank You!